# Assume that previous tasks completed if last task is reached

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that has three data flow tasks i.e.

1) Load data from file 1 into database table 1
2) Load data from file 2 into database table 2
3) Load data from file 3 into database table 3

Stage 4 involves updating a SQL Task that updates a flag in a database.  This should only happen if all three tasks complete successfully.

Can I assume that if the job gets to stage 4 that all three tasks completed successfully? When I am debugging this does appear to be the case i.e. ssis stops if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is decided by precedence constraints. You can find out about them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261.aspx

These constraints are contained in the arrows connecting shapes on the control flow. By right clicking you can view and change the constraint which decides whether to proceed or not.

By default, shapes are connected by the success constraint, meaning execution will only continue if the previous shape reported success, however it can be changed to failure or completion. Each of these constraints changes the connecting arrow to a different colour so you can quickly tell which constraint is used.